# Compress working directory

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I want to know the best way to compress the current working directory so that only the last directory's full name is visible. Let me give an example:

```
$ echo $PWD
/Users/mac/workshop/project1/src
```

I want to be able to pipe it through a series of commands such that I should get

```
~/w/p/src
```

I can obtain the first part of getting the leading `~` by doing `${PWD/#$HOME/\~}`

```
$ echo ${PWD/#$HOME/\~}
~/workshop/project1/src
```

What do I pipe the rest through so that I get

```
$ echo ${PWD/#$HOME/\~} | ...
~/w/p/src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo ${PWD/#$HOME/\~} |
sed -e 's%/\([^/]\)[^/]\{1,\}/%/\1/%g' \
    -e 's%/\([^/]\)[^/]\{1,\}/%/\1/%g'
```

The repeated regex is necessary because the pattern matches, for example, the `/src/` in `~/src/perl/DBD/Informix/lib/DBD/Informix`, and the matching resumes with the `p` of `perl`, which isn't a slash, so it doesn't match immediately.  You can see what happens by replacing the `g` with `gp`.

Example:

```
$ echo $PWD
/Users/jleffler/src/perl/DBD-Informix/lib/DBD/Informix
$ echo ${PWD/#$HOME/\~} |
> sed -e 's%/\([^/]\)[^/]\{1,\}/%/\1/%g' -e 's%/\([^/]\)[^/]\{1,\}/%/\1/%g'
~/s/p/D/l/D/Informix
$

$ echo ${PWD/#$HOME/\~} |
> sed -e 's%/\([^/]\)[^/]\{1,\}/%/\1/%gp' -e 's%/\([^/]\)[^/]\{1,\}/%/\1/%gp'
~/s/perl/D/lib/D/Informix
~/s/p/D/l/D/Informix
~/s/p/D/l/D/Informix
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Command :

```
sed "s/\/home\/[^\/]*/~/;s_/\(.\)[^/]*_/\1_g" <<<"/home/ssam/Documents/so"
```

Output :

```
~/D/s
```

Command :

```
sed "s/\/home\/[^\/]*/~/;s_/\(.\)[^/]*_/\1_g" <<<"/homey/singo/Documents/so"
```

Output :

```
/h/s/D/s
```